# ASP.NET and EF are very very slow

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

By using EF, C# and ASP.NET 4 web application, I use following code to retrieve data from database and fill GridView:

```
using (AshModel am = this.conn.GetContext())
{
    IEnumerable<Article> articles = 
        (from a in am.Article.AsEnumerable()
         where (a.CultureName == calture || a.CultureName == 0)
             && a.IsApproved == status
             && a.IsPublished == status
         orderby a.AddedDate descending
         select a);

    IEnumerable<Profile> profiles = am.Profile.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(t => articles.Any(a => a.ProfileId == t.ProfileID));

    foreach (Article article in articles)
        article.UserProfile = profiles
            .Where(a => a.ProfileID == article.ProfileId)
            .FirstOrDefault();

    this.gvArticles.DataSource = articles.ToList();
    this.gvArticles.DataBind();
}
```

but it is very very slow, It takes about 2 minutes to response, There are only 500 records in database! What is(are) my mistake(s)? How I can improve performance?
thanks.

Comment: Are both the application and the databse on the same machine?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are doing `AsEnumerable()` in some parts.

When you do that, All the objects are being retrieved from the database and after that they're filtered.

If you remove those `AsEnumerable()` it should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, as you said, I remove AsEnumerable() and got this error: Unable to create a constant value of type 'Ash.Entities.Article'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context :(

Comment: Ok, supose it's because of `IEnumerable<Article> articles =...`, a query does not return an IEnumerable, it returns an IQueryable<T>, change it to `var articles =...` and you should be ok

Comment: Also, beware you are updating your Articles, when you do `foreach (Article article in articles)article.UserProfile = profiles.Where(a => a.ProfileID == article.ProfileId).FirstOrDefault();` you are updating that object, if you then execute a context.SaveChanges they will be updated. If you have a property named UserProfile, I suspect it has been created through a relationship, so there is no need to explicitly fill it, Linq will do if you have lazy load enabled, else you can use  `am.Article.Include("Article.UserInfo")` and in this way you can remove that.

Comment: @Gusman, exactly, but you should use Include("UserProfile"), not Include("Article.UserProfile"), otherwise it will try to include Article in Article

Comment: @Gusman: I change IEnumerable<Article> articles =... to var ..., but I  got that error again. it was occured in article.UserProfile = profiles.Where(a => a.ProfileID == article.ProfileId).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: Remove that part of code, look at my previous comment

Comment: @Gusman: If I remove that part, I should use JOIN Article & Profile?

Answer (score 1):

Your second and third part can be replaced with simple `Include` expression:

```
 var articles = 
    (from a in am.Article
     .Include(article=>article.UserProfile) //!!
     where (a.CultureName == calture || a.CultureName == 0)
         && a.IsApproved == status
         && a.IsPublished == status
     orderby a.AddedDate descending
     select a).ToList();

//no more DB calls in foreach loop

this.gvArticles.DataSource = articles.ToList();
this.gvArticles.DataBind();
```

Because in your code you first select articles, then you find profiles mentioned at least in one article(can be entire set of data) and next you select profile to match for your article...

Answer (score -1):

Code like this:

```
IEnumerable<Profile> profiles = am.Profile.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(t => articles.Any(a => a.ProfileId == t.ProfileID));
```

does not cause an actual collection/list/whatever to be instantiated. This is merely a recipe describing how to retrieve and filter objects, but the lambda expression within the `Where` clause is not executed in the above line. It's only an expression that defines how to generate items in the `profiles` collection, but it does not generate them.

Actual execution of that code happens as soon as any of the items is requested, in your example it occurs on `.FirstOrDefault()` call. However, it is within a loop.
In effect, you are requerying DB with every step of the loop.

Since it is much faster to load a bunch of DB records at once, rather than load them individually, I suggest rewriting your query to the `Profile` table, so that it loads all it needs in as few transactions as possible. For you it would mean changing the first lines of your code snippet to:

```
IList<Article> articles = 
    (from a in am.Article
     where (a.CultureName == calture || a.CultureName == 0)
         && a.IsApproved == status
         && a.IsPublished == status
     orderby a.AddedDate descending
     select a).ToList();

IList<Profile> profiles = am.Profile.Where(t => articles.Any(a => a.ProfileId == t.ProfileID)).ToList();
```

All in all, code is not necessarily executed in the place it occurs. You might want to google *deferred execution* in C#.